# How not to require choosing a channel when authorizing a Slack App?

Tags: slack, slack-api

For a toy app I'm building right now, I've defined some post-installation actions so that a channel is automatically created for the app and the user who installed the app is invited to the channel. However, every time during installation I'd need to select an existing channel for the Slack App (see the red box in the screenshot):

[image]

I have seen some other apps which do not require this selection of channel during installation. So my question is: What can I do to remove this selection from the installation process? Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to choose Channel comes up when the developer have **enabled 'Incoming Webhooks'** 
More details here : 
 https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#create_a_webhook

Comment: Can I remove this option completely? I don't need the user to choose a channel because a channel will be created and the user will be invited.

Comment: You can disable 'Incoming Webhooks' toggle button and you are good.

Comment: But isn't `Incoming Webhooks` needed for other communications during installation?

Comment: This will depend on the use-case. Normally incoming webhooks must be avoided as they do not have any authorization mechanism. Ideally  you should use webapi like chat.postMessage : https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: After disabling `Incoming Webhooks`, the `Where should XXX post?` option is still in the `oauth` page...am I missing a step?

Comment: "Activate Incoming Webhooks" toggle button must be "off "

Comment: I had it turned off but for Django and realized that `incoming-webhook` must be removed from the `SLACK_SCOPES` env var :) Thanks again!